# Strange hover behavior in the sidebar jquery and bootstrap menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, navbar

I´m doing a big project based on Boostrap 3 template, that uses a lot of jQuery plugins to cover the project needs. Everything is going well!

You can see 3 project sample pages here:

[www.frontsite.com.br/saam2/index.php?_action=mapa](http://www.frontsite.com.br/saam2/index.php?_action=mapa)

[www.frontsite.com.br/saam2/index.php?_action=painel](http://www.frontsite.com.br/saam2/index.php?_action=painel)

[www.frontsite.com.br/saam2/index.php?_action=arquivo](http://www.frontsite.com.br/saam2/index.php?_action=painel)

Both pages has a "left content menu/bar". Its a scrollable containter `div` with a collapsible list of nested items `ul` and `li`, as you can see.

```
<div class="sidebar-operacional">
...
   <div class="col-md-12 nav-hierarq" id="barra-lateral-operacional">
```

Each nested item of my list shows a short list of small blue, red and grey `span` buttons, each one with its self function/action. Doing well!

**The problem is - very strange:**
On Google Chrome (i didnt tested on others), when the items of my list are expanded/opened (it shows the minus sign button in the right), and when I put the mouse hover these small span buttons, its margins becomes to zero, doing an unexpected little movement of them to the left, stacking them. And when the items of my list are collapsed/closed (it shows the plus sign button in the right), and when I put the mouse hover these same span buttons, its margins returns to their original and correct positions. It occurs only with the `li` items that has children. The deepest `li` items doesn´t has the same behavior when you put the mouse hover: this should be the right behavior to all!

Strange, no?

I already spent a lot of time investigating what could be happening, whitout solution. So I´d be glad if someone could help me.

Many thanks.

Added on jan 21st:

I think this image can illustrate exatlly what´s/where happening.
The problem is occuring with the little SPAN buttons: INFO, MAPA, ARQ, COMM.
Did you try to pass the mouse hover it and see them automatcaly get closer to the nearest SPAN button beside?
I think its some unexpected CSS class overwriting issue I can´t find or locate! Anyone can help?

[image: Trying to illustrate the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deeper investigation, I found where the problem was occuring, but I really still don´t know the reason.

By the way, Im posting my **solution** in case of other people is facing a problem like this.

I was calling a Boostrap Tooltip into the `span` tag, something like this:

```
<span class="label" data-rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Gerenciar Item">
   <a class="btn" href="index.html">Ger</a>
</span>
```

When I moved the Tooltip calling to inside the `a` tag, the strange error stoped.

```
<span class="label">
   <a class="btn" href="index.html" data-rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Gerenciar Item">Ger</a>
</span>
```

But this solution was not making me satisfied! I really would like to know the reason of the tooltip calling inside `span` tags was loading wrongly.

So looking at [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), I discovered a way to call the tooltip using the parameter `container`, so I guess.

I rewrote my buttons to something like this (using the param `data-container="body"`):

```
<span class="label" data-rel="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="Gerenciar Item">
   <a class="btn" href="index.html">Ger</a>
</span>
```

And I really don´t know why, but this was the problem I was getting, and doing this little modification I avoid the problem was making me crazy.

Thanks for every help I got :)

So I hope also to help posting this.

Answer (score 0):

am i crazy or are you talking about the `scroll bar` that pushes those buttons to the left ?

[image]

from what i can see here . the scroll bar `.jspPane` gets his `width` calculated in JS

`.jspVerticalBar` has its `width` of `8px` set in CSS

easiest solution would be to add the `2px` to `.jspVerticalBar` in CSS .. or you can check and see why the width of `.jspPane` is not calculated correctly

Comment: Hi Mihnea, maybe I was not too clear enough. So I edited my question adding on it an image that could better illustrate where the problem is happening. So, could you see it again traying to help me some CSS class overwriting or what should be? Many thanks.

Comment: hi. adding 'display: inline-block' on those '.label' will fix your problem. but i'm not sure what is causing this . i think its related with http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/